# How to use a ValidateSet and still allow $null on an Array parameter?

Tags: validation, powershell

I've got a method that needs to accept an array of strings as a parameter, but that array can only contain valid strings. My problem is that if I ensure to `[AllowNull()]`, and also `[AllowEmptyCollection()]`, the method still fails

```posh
function SomethingSomethingAuthType {
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,position=0)] 
        [ValidateSet('anonymousAuthentication','basicAuthentication','clientCertificateMappingAuthentication','digestAuthentication','iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication','windowsAuthentication')] 
        [AllowNull()] 
        [AllowEmptyCollection()] 
        [array] $authTypes
    )

    $authTypes | % {
        Write-Host $_ -f Green
    }

}

SomethingSomethingAuthType $null
```

> SomethingSomethingAuthType : Cannot validate argument on parameter
>   'authTypes'. The argument is null, empty, or an element of the
>   argument collection contains a null value. Supply a  collection that
>   does not contain any null values and then try the command again. At
>   line:16 char:32
>   +     SomethingSomethingAuthType $null
>   +                                ~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [SomethingSomethingAuthType], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,SomethingSomethingAuthType

What do I need to do to allow `$null` to be passed in, but also validate the set to ensure the appropriate types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer here would be to use an `[Enum[]]` instead of `[array]`, and remove the ValidateSet all together.

```posh
function SomethingSomethingAuthType {
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,position=0)] 
        [AllowNull()] 
        [AllowEmptyCollection()] 
        [AuthType[]] $authTypes
    )

    Write-Host 'Made it past validation.'

    if(!$authTypes) { return }

    $authTypes | % {
        Write-Host "type: $_" -f Green
    }

}

# Check if the enum exists, if it doesn't, create it.
if(!("AuthType" -as [Type])){
 Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
    public enum AuthType{
        anonymousAuthentication,
        basicAuthentication,
        clientCertificateMappingAuthentication,
        digestAuthentication,
        iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication,
        windowsAuthentication    
    }
'@
}
```

```posh
# Testing
# =================================

SomethingSomethingAuthType $null                                          # will pass
SomethingSomethingAuthType anonymousAuthentication, basicAuthentication   # will pass

SomethingSomethingAuthType invalid                                        # will fail
SomethingSomethingAuthType anonymousAuthentication, invalid, broken       # will fail
```